Align DataTemplate in ListView Column
I am trying to align a 'DataTemplate' in a ListView Column, but something is going wrong as my templates are always left aligned. I tried several answers on stack (there are too much to write here), but still not working
Here is my XAML :
<GridViewColumn Width="70">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ContentControl Content="{Binding}" Grid.Column="1">
                    <ContentControl.Style>
                        <Style TargetType="ContentControl">
                            <Style.Triggers>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsTotal}" Value="{x:Static p:Resources.Pending}"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsWeight}" Value="true"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource displayWeightNotInProd}" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsTotal}" Value="{x:Static p:Resources.Pending}"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsWeight}" Value="false"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource displayTimeNotInProd}" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsTotal}" Value="{x:Static p:Resources.InProduction}"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsWeight}" Value="true"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource displayWeightInProd}" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                                <MultiDataTrigger>
                                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsTotal}" Value="{x:Static p:Resources.InProduction}"/>
                                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}, Path=IsWeight}" Value="false"/>
                                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                                    <Setter Property="ContentTemplate" Value="{StaticResource displayTimeInProd}" />
                                </MultiDataTrigger>
                            </Style.Triggers>
                        </Style>
                    </ContentControl.Style>
                </ContentControl>
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

And here are the templates :
<DataTemplate x:Key="displayWeightNotInProd">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="auto"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <!--<Label Content="{Binding TimeTotal, Converter={StaticResource timeSpanToHourMinutes}}" Foreground="#FF042271" /> -->
        <Label Content="{Binding WeightTotal, StringFormat=N1}" Foreground="#FF042271" />
        <Label Grid.Column="1" Content="T" Foreground="#FF042271"/>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>
<DataTemplate x:Key="displayWeightInProd">
    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
        <Label Foreground="#FF042271">
            <Label.Content>
                <StackPanel>
                    <Grid>
                        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                            <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" Text="{Binding WeightTotalInProd, StringFormat=N1}"/>
                        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" Text=" T"/>
                    </Grid>
                </StackPanel>
            </Label.Content>
        </Label>
    </Grid>
</DataTemplate>

I tried (almost) everywhere to play with HorizontalAlignment, HorizontalContentAlignment, but my template is always left aligned.

I ran into this issue before, I fixed it by setting width="..." to the main Grid on DataTemplate, because it is using the actual width when it is rendering , that why you didn't notice any difference.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/controls/how-to-share-sizing-properties-between-grids?view=netframeworkdesktop-4.8

@MustafaMutasim it solved it perfectly. Could you write please an answer, so I could close the question.  Thanks

Workarounds:
1. Fixed Width on the main Grid
<GridViewColumn Width="70">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="70" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                ...
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

2. Binding to GridViewColumn | Width or ActualWidth
<GridViewColumn Width="70" x:Name="GridColumn_1">
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid Width="{Binding ElementName=GridColumn_1,Path=ActualWidth}" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                ...
                ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

3. Set HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" on the child that support it
<GridViewColumn Width="70" >
    <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                <Label HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" Foreground="#FF042271"/>
                    ...
                    ...
            </Grid>
        </DataTemplate>
    </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
</GridViewColumn>

